# Typing status when input field is typed in

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, socket.io

I'm trying to make a status popup upon typing. It's like when you are typing in the message input bar to another person with any social media app, it alerts the user to know the other end is responding back to you.

This is basically an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Here is an attempt but does not work at all how I would like it to. It currently detects as soon as the user inputs text into the input, but does not disappear when the user has sent the message (which clears the input) I've also attempted to hide the div in a function when the message was sent, but that did not work either. Here is my current attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#msg").on("input", function(){
        document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = "Typing...";
    });
});
```

```
<span id="typing"></span>

<form id="chat-form">
<input id="msg" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to start a timer and remove the text after a certain amount of time. Here's an updated version of your code that works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tmo = null;
  $("#msg").on("input", function(){
    document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = "Typing...";
    
    if (tmo) {
      clearTimeout(tmo);
    }
    tmo = setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = "";
    }, 1000);
    
  });  
});
```

I created a code pen with a working solution: https://codepen.io/familjenpersson/pen/YzGmWOv

Answer (score 1):

When enter key is pressed the input goes away.

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('#msg');
const typingElement = document.querySelector('#typing')

inputElement.addEventListener("keyup", handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  // When enter reset typing and stop.
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    typingElement.innerText = '';
    return;
  }
  
  typingElement.innerText = 'typing...';
  
}
```

```html
<span id="typing"></span>

<form id="chat-form">
<input id="msg" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```